# Implement ng2-dnd drop zone restriction issues

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, drag

I implemented drag and drop functionality using `ng2-dnd`  for my Angular 4 application. I have containers which can be sorted and items within each container which can also be sorted.

I want to restrict items within each containers from being re-assigned to another container.

There is a Container 1 and Container 2. Container 1 has Item1, Item2 and Container 2 has Item3, Item4. I want to restrict Item1 from being dropped into Container 2.

I tried using `[allowDrop]="allowDropFunction()"` but it did not work. What function can i use to restrict the drop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropzones to allow dropping of an element into a target container. For example on the element you want to drag:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true" [dropZones]="['zone1', 'zone2']">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div>Drag Me</div>
    <div>Zone 1 & 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then on the target container(s):

```
<div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-info" [dropZones]="['zone1']" (onDropSuccess)="restrictedDrop1=$event">
    <div class="panel-heading">Zone 1</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div *ngIf="restrictedDrop1">Item was dropped here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-warning" [dropZones]="['zone2']" (onDropSuccess)="restrictedDrop2=$event">
    <div class="panel-heading">Zone 2</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div *ngIf="restrictedDrop2">Item was dropped here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as the element that you want to drag has a matching dropzone in its dropZones property (which can be a string or an array), then the element can be dropped into the target container.

If want to change the dropzones you can do so dynamically using property binding.